# Disable popup on double click event on Mapbox GL map

Tags: web-mapping, popup, mapbox-gl

How to disable 'show popup' on 'double click' (show popup only on 'single click' event) event without disabling 'zoom in' (or 'zoom out' (with Shift button))?

[Mapbox GL jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rf8hjgt4/)

Answer (score 2):

You can track the following event. While double click it's always:

1. click
2. click
3. double click

Exactly in this order.

So:

```
let dbl = false;

  map.on("click", "boundary", function(e) {
    dbl = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!dbl) {
        new mapboxgl.Popup()
          .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
          .setHTML("popup content")
          .addTo(map);
      }
    }, 500)
  });
  
  map.on("dblclick", "boundary", function(e) {
    dbl = true;
  });
```

Should do the job. You simply need a small timeout, you can decrease that 0.5s, and check if a click event has been followed by the dblclick.